# Flutter-Firebase authentication login button navigate to first screen

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am try to set navigate this button when login is successful but its not working. how can I fix this

```
onPressed: () async {

    if (_formStateKey.currentState.validate()) {
    _formStateKey.currentState.save();
    signUp(_emailId, _password).then((user) {

        if (user != null ) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/ilk');

        } else {
        print('Error while Login.');
        }
    });
    }
},
```

this is sign up part.

```
Future<FirebaseUser> signUp(email, password) async {
    try {
    FirebaseUser user = (await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password)) as FirebaseUser;
    assert(user != null);
    assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

    return user;
    } catch (e) {
    handleError(e);
    return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your main.dart file

Comment: ı shared all code my login page.dart

Comment: you are saying when login is not successful, but your method is for registration.

Comment: my login is successfull but my after the login my navigate route doesnt working

Comment: check whether you gave the name of the page currently. During navigation

Comment: I checked everything looks true but I dont get it, its navigation its not working